# Google App Script get (MID) string from named range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a newbie with GAS and this is my first question on Stackoverflow. Hopefully I can explain my question in a correct manor for you.

I have 2 sheets in 1 spreadsheet named "INPUT" & "DATA".
On the INPUT sheet there is a named range called "ScanNr" (the value is always 18 digits)

The value of this named range needs to be copied to sheet DATA (col A) in a new row.

At the moment I'm using a MID-formula in sheet DATA (col B) to get a part of the scannr.

Can you help me adjust the script so I don't have to use a formula?
An example of the current formula is "=MID(A5, 8, 4)"

This is my code sofar:

```
    function SaveScan() {
    var ss       = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var myForm   = ss.getSheetByName("INPUT");
    var myData   = ss.getSheetByName("DATA");
    
    var myScan   = myForm.getRange("ScanNr").getValue();
      
      myData.getRange(myData.getLastRow()+1, 1).setValue(myScan);
  //  myData.getRange(myData.getLastRow(), 2)  // ?? I don't know how to do this.

    }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification? I think that `=MID(A5, 8, 4)` can be converted to `value.substr(7, 4)` using Javascript. And, in your situation, I thought that `appendRow` might be suitable.

#### From:

```
myData.getRange(myData.getLastRow()+1, 1).setValue(myScan);
```

#### To:

```
myData.appendRow([myScan, myScan.substr(7, 4)]);
```

#### References:

- [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

Comment: Great! Thank you Tanaike, this is exactly what I needed and a clear approach for me to understand.